# Sound not working 12.04 after update

Tags: 12.04, sound, updates, alsa, soundcard

my sound was working perfectly fine while suddenly it stopped after an update... I tried reinstalling alsamixer and stuff - did not work.
When I start alsamixer, here is what i get:

[image]

Also in the upper right corner, when the sound menu is opened, the slider is inactive, same for the options in the Settings. Here is what I get with:

```
$ lspci | grep -i 
audio00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 0a0c (rev 0b)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

Here is another:

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [MID            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel MID
                  HDA Intel MID at 0xf2610000 irq 62
1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                  HDA Intel PCH at 0xf2614000 irq 63
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your main soundcard is the 2nd one (the first is HDMI soundcard, attached to HDMI screen plug) .

So , in **Alsamixer**, press F6 , select 2nd soundcard : you will see more faders .Then set volumes and unmute faders (using arrow keys and "m" key to unmute. )

You can also install and run **pavucontrol** (Pulseaudio volume control) to access the 2nd sound card in the **"output device"** tab (click **green button** near it to make it default)